# PIL - Python - Use the palette of one image into another

Tags: python, blender

I'm using PIL inside Blender 3.3 and I have some images that I group into a bigger one, then quantize the groupped image to 16 colors and get the palette.

What I want is to apply this "global" palette to the separate images that form the bigger one and get an indexed image. Here is what I have:

```
for group_id, images in grouped_images.items():
    # Stack the images together
    stacked_image = Image.new('RGB', (images[0][1].width, images[0][1].height * len(images)))
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(images):
        stacked_image.paste(value, (0, i * value.height))

    # Generate a 16-color palette for the stacked image
    quantized_stacked_image = stacked_image.quantize(colors=16, dither=Image.NONE, method=Image.MEDIANCUT)
    palette_data = quantized_stacked_image.getpalette()
    
    print("palette_data out:", palette_data)
    
    # Use the generated palette to quantize each image in the group individually
    for key, value in images:
    
        palimage = Image.new('P', (16, 16))
        palimage.putpalette(palette_data)
        palimage.load()

        quantized_image = value.convert("RGB")
        quantized_image = quantized_image.convert("P", dither=Image.NONE, palette=palimage.im)
```

The problem here is that **quantized_image** doesn't get the palette applied, if I run .getcolors() on it, I get color index values out of the 0-15 palette range.

**palette_data** seems to be correct, contains a list where only the first 48 (16xRGB) values are used.

I have also tried with:

```
quantized_image = value.quantize(dither=Image.NONE, palette=quantized_stacked_image)
```

But same result.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Just to clarify what I'm trying to do, let's say I have 4 pictures; I want to generate a unique 16 color palette that I will use for the 4 of them separately. First, I group all four images into a single one, quantize it and extract the palette. Then I want to use that 16 color palette I just got and use it in every one of those 4 pictures separately. The first part works fine, I get the “global” palette, but then it doesn’t work when I try to apply it to the images separately

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do. Could you maybe show the images?

Comment: Let's say I have 4 pictures; I want to generate a unique 16 color palette that I will use for the 4 of them separately. First, I group all four images into a single one, quantize it and extract the palette. Then I want to use that 16 color palette I just got and use it in every one of those 4 pictures separately.
The first part works fine, I get the “global” palette, but then it doesn’t work when I try to apply it to the images separately.

Comment: I think you should edit the question and add that comment. It's helpful.